# Integrating with AWS from our website, services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We are building a SAAS website. Some of the features require the AWS services of our users to be operated via our website.
Users may or may not chose these features, but if they wish to, they should be able to grant certain permissions to us. Our website has https with our own authentication mechanism.

Question :

1) What are the industry best practices of doing AWS integration in these scenarios ?

2) We bounced upon these articles on aws.amazon.com. When do we use 'Role for an IAM user' approach vs 'Role for Identity Federation options' ?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html

3) The step of 'granting an IAM role' using AWS, before using AWS services on our product is considered by us as an user experience shortcoming. Is this unavoidable?

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: I think this question is too much things and you should hire a AWS SA for your problem.

Comment: This is a solved problem. See how other SAAS providers do this, for example: https://support.cloudcheckr.com/cross-account-roles/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 -** Only request access from your users what you need to operate your SAAS. It lowers the risk of you being breached and your customers being affected. If you only need readonly access to EC2, for example, then only request read-only access.

<strike>To operate your customers AWS accounts you'll need more than just a user and role created. To make API calls your customers will have to generate a access key and secrete key for you to use. Thats what your site will use to communicate with AWS on their behalf. This is essentially just a private key so in terms of security best practices you will need to treat it like you would any very sensitive resource. Storing credentials like this in s3 is one option and/or DynamoDB.</strike>

**2 -** <strike>Role for federation is for when someone logs into AWS using credentials from an external Identity provider outside of AWS (SAML/SSO). You don't need this; customers aren't logging into your AWS account and you're not logging into theirs. The Role you need is optional. Your customer can create a role, attach permissions to it, then attach the role to a user and give that user to you. They can also just create the user and put the permissions directly on the user but the role approach is a better practice.</strike> What you really need to find out is what AWS resources do you need access to and what do you want to do with them. From that there are a list of needed permissions for that resource. You'll have to send your customers instructions on how to <strike>create a user,</strike> create a role, attach the needed permissions<strike>, then generate an API key for you to use.</strike>

**3 -** <strike>A role is not necessary, its optional. What's required is that your customers create a role, give it the permissions for each AWS service you need access to and only the ones you need access to,then generate keys for you to use in your API calls. But overall the user experience is still the same. If your target customers are regular AWS customers this will be easy for them but I doubt regular AWS customers would need someone else to manage their account.</strike>

Role assignment is unavoidable if your taking the cleanest approach.

**Update**

See JamieStarke comments below. An easier approach for your customers, and more secure would be for them to assign a role to your AWS account so no key exchange is needed. If your not using AWS as your core infrastructure you can open an account and still have them assign the role to that account  In either approach no credentials need to be exchanged with you and the customer.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: *"To operate your customers AWS accounts you'll need more than just a user and role created."*  Justify this, assertion, please.  Only a role should be necessary.  You assume it when you want to work under its auspices.

Comment: I tend to agree with Michael on this. The best practice I've seen in the industry is not to generate another access key using long term credentials, but for the customer to create a Cross Account Access role, that you assume, thus giving you the permissions of that role. I handle whatever credentials on my side that give me access to the role, the customer determines what that role can do.

Comment: @JamieStarke How will his web site programmatically manage AWS accounts without an access key? He's building a SAAS solution.

Comment: If he's building on top of AWS, his servers could have IAM Roles associated with them that are granted access to assume the roles of the customers. With Instance roles, AWS Manages the credentials for you, and they get rotated frequently.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm in favor of attaching a new role to my infrastructure for each customer. So my EC2 instances will be updated with a new role for each account I manage? It would be far cleaner to isolate each request to the accessKey that is needed, when its needed. I'd rather treat customers like data and keep my infrastructure immutable. Changing or re-assigning roles would require a stack-update in cloudformation, all for a single customer addition.

Comment: Ok, lets suppose they're not. The best practice in that case would be for them to create their own AWS account in which they create their own IAM users, so that they can rotate their own credentials. The customer creates a cross account Role, and grants access to their account, so that their SAAS solutions IAM User can assume that Role. That one IAM Can then assume the roles of all of the customers.

Comment: "Changing or re-assigning roles would require a stack-update in cloudformation, all for a single customer addition" <- False, you use the API to assume the Role, which generates you temporary credentials you can use to access their resources.

Comment: [Tutorial: Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

Comment: @JamieStarke I think your second solution is a good one. Post it...With regard to stack-updates, if your keeping everything your stack needs in CloudFormation using the API to change roles would break the pattern of immutability I was suggesting. Of course its possible to make changes outside of cloudformation but that defeats the purpose and is off topic any how.